# What happens to executing JS when user closes window (or nav away from it)?

Tags: javascript

ScenarioA: synchronous functionA is executed. The user closes the window in the middle of functionA executing. Does execution of code simply stop as soon as the window is closed (or refreshed)? Imagine functionA makes many modifications of a db. Is it possible the db will be altered from the code in the first half of the function? If so, this could cause a problem in my project. Is there a way we can ensure the whole function is completed?

ScenarioB: `setTimeout` has a callback that executes after some time. The window's closed (just) before the callback's placed on the call-stack. Will the callback ever execute or is it just discarded?

Comment: A) browser will kill it  B) It is just discarded.

Comment: This is what database transactions are good for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does execution of code simply stop as soon as the window is closed (or refreshed)?

Yes.

> Imagine functionA makes many modifications of a db. Is it possible the db will be altered from the code in the first half of the function?

Yes.

> If so, this could cause a problem in my project. Is there a way we can ensure the whole function is completed?

No.

In general, with databases, you can use transactions so if the complete set of changes isn't completed it will rollback.

> ScenarioB: setTimeout has a callback that executes after some time. The window's closed (just) before the callback's placed on the call-stack. Will the callback ever execute or is it just discarded?

It is discarded.